# How to represent and read 4D array in Opl Cplex from Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, cplex, opl, 4d

How can I represent and read a 4D array from Excel to Opl Cplex? 
The 3D IBM array link is not helpful, trying to adapt to 4D does not work.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use SheetRead to read a tuple set "input" from Excel:

```
tuple t
{
string k;
string l;
string i;
string t;
float cost;

}

{t} input=...;
```

and then convert this tuple set into a 4D array:

```
float cost[K][L][I][T];

    execute

    {

    for(var x in input) cost[x.k][x.l][x.i][x.t]=x.cost;

    }
```

NB: I dealt with this at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/read4Darray.mod and https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/read4Darray.dat