# Problem with converting Tuple into 4D array in OPL

Tags: cplex, opl

I am working with the IBM Ilog Studio/OPL.

I want to transform a tuple, that I am reading out of an excel data file into an (4D)array.
A similar question has been raised before, but the given answer does not work in may case and I cannot find the reason. Here the link.

[How to represent and read 4D array in Opl Cplex from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489646/how-to-represent-and-read-4d-array-in-opl-cplex-from-excel?newreg=09711d4bea734636a101ab462387a4e5)

The reading of the tuple from excel works (I have checked that the "start" is read correctly).
The Tuple in the mod. file is defined as:

```
tuple mipstart { 
int  i;
int q;
int d;
int k;
int value; }


{mipstart} start =...;

int valuemip[I][Q][D][K]; 

execute
{
for(var x in start) valuemip[x.i][x.q][x.d][x.k]=x.value;
}
```

The error message I get is that "the value valuemip#0 is outside of the valid range (0)." The indexes (I,Q,D,K) are all declared to be ranges starting with 1....
In other words I am trying to build the 4D array "valuemip" from the tuple start.

(For further information: In .dat file "test" is the named data space --> works)

```
start from SheetRead (sheet, "test");
```

I am new at working with tuples and have previously mainly used the "basic student" use of IBM Ilog Studio (writing a model (mainly with arrays) in a mod file and having a corresponding dat file with data read frome Excel).

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but experience suggests that transforming a set of tuples into am array is almost always a backwards step. Most models end up being simpler and clearer if you work with sets of tuples rather than arrays. Try it - you might like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may come from your data if tuple members are zero and end up used as valuemip indices.

Answer (score 0):

I would recompute yur ranges out of the tuple set:

```
tuple mipstart { 
int  i;
int q;
int d;
int k;
int value; }


{mipstart} start ={<1,2,3,4,100>};

{int} I={e.i | e in start};
{int} Q={e.q | e in start};
{int} D={e.d | e in start};
{int} K={e.k | e in start};

int valuemip[I][Q][D][K]; 

execute
{
for(var x in start) valuemip[x.i][x.q][x.d][x.k]=x.value;
}
```

works fine